# Will signing assemblies reduce performance

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I'm building a website that requires high performance and wondering if signing the assemblies will reduce performance. (Server has to verify on every request?) Does anyone have experience with this? or is it simply negligible?

**Update**

What exactly does the verification process involve?

Is there any difference between self-signed and 3rd party signed? (will it verify with a 3rd party server somewhere?)

Comment: not really, you may improve by 0.000001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, strong signing your assemblies will not impact performance.